# CML pre driver tail node voltage

Tags: voltage, driver, current-source, transmission-line

Please consider the following schematic. I want to understand the V(A) waveform, when D+ & D- are switching.[image]

My understanding is that during the switch, we will have overshoot on V(A), because during the brief amount of time, both differential MOS are ON and so we have lesser net resistance and hence lesser voltage drop from VDD.

Comment: Do you mean when D+ = D- = VDD/2, there will be a voltage surge at the node A? Also, into which node you think the net resistance is lesser when both transistors are on?

Comment: Yes i mean that voltage will rise on node A when D+ = D-. The net resistance between VDD and node A will be lesser at that time, but since we have current source at the bottom, so current will still be the same, which will make lesser voltage drop between supply & node A. This is my understanding